# In a list, skip a host that I cannnot access

Tags: python, bash, ssh

SOLVED:

I figured out the fix for this was adding `env.abort_on_prompts = True` to my fab file

---

This is a very specific question ... but I have a python definition that checks for the OS version of a specific host. It goes line by line through the list, attempts to connect to the host and outputs the OS information it finds. But that is just background ...

So my real question is if I can skip the hosts I cannot access. Many hosts it does fine with, but it will hit one where the screen prompts for "Login password for 'yourAdminUser':". I want to know if there is a way that I can get the script to realize when this is being output to the console, that it should terminate that connection attempt and then move on to the next line.

I would paste my code but it is only a few lines and I have nothing in it to expect this error of a password that I do not have.

Thanks

EDIT : I've pasted my definition below.

```
def get_os():
    put(local_path="scripts/check_OS.ksh",remote_path="/tmp/check_OS.ksh")
    sudo('chmod u+x /tmp/check_OS.ksh')
    output = sudo("/tmp/check_OS.ksh")
    print green("OS: {}".format(output))
```

Comment: What are you using to connect to each host?  Need to find out how that library or tool is prompting on the console, in order to detect it, or bypass it e.g by using a `pty` (it's also crucial what environment you're running on -- if Windows, I believe `pty`s are not supported and don't know how to work around **that**).

Comment: Post the code anyway. At this point you haven't even told us how you're connecting to the hosts.

Comment: Please click `edit` underneath your question and paste your code into your question rather than in ill-formatted, difficult-to-read comments. Indent by 4 spaces. Thank you.

Comment: It's `fabric`, and you can set `env` variable `skip_bad_hosts` to bypass unreachable hosts. So add `env.skip_bad_hosts = True` above the task definition.

Comment: Also, `env.warn_only = True` will just throw a warning rather than an error on any `run`, `sudo` or `local` errors.